# Ad tag not working

Tags: javascript, tags, ads

I am trying to integrate first ad tag no my website with very little front end knowledge.

So far, I have placed the snippet provided by the ad company in the 'head' segment and the ad agency has confirmed that they are able to see the user data.

However I am not able to see any ads on my website yet. What kind of code do I need to add to be able to see the ads?

I also have some size snippets from the agency without instruction, so again I dont know how to use it!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function() {
   var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
   var src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + 
   '//adagency.com/services/tag/js/4011.js?time=' + (new Date().getTime()) ;
  document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + src + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
})();
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe code isn't active yet. Wait a day and check again.

Comment: Already waited for more than 4 days, still no luck. I have a feeling I haven't used the above mentioned snippet in the right place/way.

Comment: Contact this script provider. Example link https://adagency.com/services/tag/js/4011.js?time=1511988035709 shows nothing, and its loading and loading. I think there is error on their side. We can't help You with this. Sorry.

Comment: Many thanks for your tips. The problem was actually with the agency's script only. Got it working now. Can someone also give me a tip about what I have to do to make the right size ad displayed based on the device type? I have got the JS snippets for 5 sizes but not sure what to do with them.

Comment: Contact agency for that.